# Getting the chosen option of a Relationships fieldtype field

Tags: relationships

I recently upgraded from 2.5.5 to 2.7 and I am doing a number of fixes to make my code up compatible with the new version.

I have a channel field called `foo` which is of the Relationships fieldtype.

When I tried outputting `{foo}` it outputs 0

```
{exp:channel:form
   channel="a_channel"
}
...
{foo} <-- outputs 0
{/exp:channel:form}
```

My problem is, how do I get the value/id of the currently chosen `foo` value?

I haven't seen any documentation about this. This is a generic, common to do so I thought they have something for it.

**UPDATE**:

I tried this as per [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/#selected-option-my-field-name)

```
 {exp:channel:form
       channel="a_channel"
    }
    ...
    {selected_option:foo}
 {/exp:channel:form}
```

But it did not work also

*It is also important to note that this is a custom field*

Answer (score 1):

I believe based on the EE Relationship documentation (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html) you would do the following:

```
{foo}
     {foo:entry_id}
{/foo}
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that it loops through all the options. I just want to get 1 entry_id, the one that is chosen by the user.